# Sorting in array java

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, for-loop, if-statement

I have this code:

*Flight.java*

```
public static Flight[] sortFlight(Flight []f)
{
    for(int i =f.length;i>=0;--i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) 
        {
            int myFlightNum1 = f[i].getFlight_number();
            int myFlightNum2 = f[j].getFlight_number();

        if(myFlightNum1>myFlightNum2)
            {
            int temp = f[i].getFlight_number();
            f[i].setFlight_number(myFlightNum2);
            f[j].setFlight_number(temp);

            }
        }
    }
return (f);
```

I want to sort the array based on flight number. I have tried `Arrays.sort`, but it keeps on saying cannot be cast to `java.lang.comparable`.

*FlightTest.java*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flight[] f = {

            new Flight("US Air","Boston","Los Angeles", 347),
            new Flight("Delta","Pheladelphia","London",212),
            new Flight("Continental","Atlanta","Chicago",822)
            };

    System.out.println("This flight information is sorted based on flight number:");

    for (Flight flights : f)
        {

        System.out.println(flights);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide `Comparator` in `sort` method as second parameter:

```
Arrays.sort(f, Comparator.comparing(Flight::getFlight_number));
```

`Comparable` interface is not a must really.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to have your `Flight` class implement the [comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.  This would guarantee that it has to implement the `compareTo()` method, where you will have to define how to compare one `Flight` object with another.

Answer (score 0):

If your Flight object implements Comparable and there you can set your own logic for comparing the fields you need then you could just use Arrays.sort() function. See here for an example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_super.htm